# Is cache packages safe to use ? (flutter)

Tags: flutter

I have questions about two packages [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) and [just_audio_cache](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio_cache) :

1-Can anyone (user, attacker, hacker...etc) get the cached (images/auidos) files on the phone and steal them ? or they are secure ?

2- Can anyone get the (images/audios)'s links ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I suggest you ask on the [Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

`cached_network_image` is one of the most popular and trusted packages on put dev so we can say that it's pretty safe from any vulnerabilities and threats but `just_audio_cache` is not safe and popular you should avoid this if your data is too sensitive

Comment: indeed "cached_network_image" is one of the most popular packes, but how can be sure about the security of the images and the urls ? (i read about it and it's using this package"flutter_cache_manager", but couldnt find anything about security)